# Could not parse '4/12/2016 > 12:00:00 AM' as TIMESTAMP for field

Tags: sql, types, google-bigquery, timestamp, schema

question from beginner in BigQuery and data analytics.

What I want to do : uploading csv file in Bigquery.

- columns of Dataset : Id, ActivityHour, StepTotal
  (1503960366, 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM, 373)

1. Problem : When I upload it with Schema (Auto detect) option, then error below.
   Question : Could you please help me how I can upload data?

> Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '4/12/2016
> 12:00:00 AM' as TIMESTAMP for field ActivityHour (position 1) starting
> at location 27 with message 'Invalid time zone: AM'

2. Problem : So I added field manually as "Id:Integer, ActivityHour:Timestamp, StepTotal:Integer" but error again

> Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'Id' as INT64
> for field Id (position 0) starting at location 0 with message 'Unable
> to parse'

3. Problem : So I added field manually as all columns : String.
   It uploaded successfully.
   But when I try to change the datatype (SQL): SELECT CAST(Id as INTEGER)
   error again "Bad int64"

Now I have no idea how to proceed the next step

Comment: 3rd Option should have worked. check if there is a bad data for ID column, which is not INTEGER.

Comment: great, Thanks. I found that header was duplicated in the table. now can upload it with type (Id : Integer, ActivityHour: String, StepTotal:Integer) and 'Header rows to skip' : 1.